# Loop executing infinite times

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, infinite-loop

Could you please tell me what the error could be?

```
for (int r=[list count]-1; r>=0;r--) {
            NSMutableArray *temp;
            temp=[list objectAtIndex:r];
            [list insertObject:temp atIndex:r++];
        }
```

At the first call, [list count] is 2.

Answer (score 4):

You're incrementing your loop variable `r` inside the loop, so it can never decrement to zero.

You need to change this line:

```
        [list insertObject:temp atIndex:r++];
```

to perhaps:

```
        [list insertObject:temp atIndex:r + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop because the loop starts passing the test (r == 1 && 1 >= 0) and from that point, r never changes. You simply grab the object at r (1) and insert it at r (1) and then increment r (r == 2). Finally, the loop ends, r gets decremented (r == 1) and you run your test again (1 >= 0 ) so it runs the loop and the exact same thing happens.

You probably want to insert temp at the next index (r + 1) but that will cause a crash since your array has only 2 places. You would need to do an addObject: in order to increase the size of the array (and to insert the item at r + 1 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Paul’s right. Maybe you think that `r++` is a shorthand for `r+1`? It’s not, it means `r=r+1`.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I realized that as soon as I posted.